# Thread is being aborted exception when using SemaphoreSlim

Tags: .net, asynchronous, semaphore

I was having an issue with Thread was being aborted exception that was solved in this post
[Thread was being aborted error when making a service call from async method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53819009/thread-was-being-aborted-error-when-making-a-service-call-from-async-method?noredirect=1#comment94487679_53819009)

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
using (var throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(10))
{
  foreach (var cust in e.customers)
  {
    await throttler.WaitAsync();
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
    {
      try
      {
        exMan.perfomAction(cust, userId);
      }
      finally
      {
        throttler.Release();
      }
    }));
  }
}
   Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

If I make exMan.perfomAction asynchonous and pass throttler into the method like this, it works. I don't know why it works if it's interfering with the async process and if this is approach has any downsides?

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
using (var throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(10))
{
  foreach (var cust in e.customers)
  {
    tasks.Add(exMan.perfomAction(cust, userId, throttler));
  }
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

public async Task performAction(Customer customer, string userId, SemaphoreSlim throttler)
{
  await throttler.WaitAsync();

  //--Do stuff (service calls, DB calls, export to file

  throttler.Release();
}
```

**EDIT**

So I've made two changes that seems to of made a difference and is working as expected. The service call has been made async and is awaited.

```
var axPriceList = await client.findExAsync(callContext, queryCriteria, documentContext);
```

The root call which calls the method containing the code below is now awaited

```
private async Task CallingMethod(string cust, string userId)
{
  await MehodA(string cust, string userId);
}

private async Task MehodA(string cust, string userId)
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    using (var throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(10))
    {
      foreach (var cust in e.customers)
      {
        tasks.Add(tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
        {
          try
          {
            await exMan.perfomAction(cust, userId);
          }
          finally
          {
            throttler.Release();
          }
        }));
      }
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Comment: That error means that the application terminated while the semaphore was still blocking execution. That's what happens eg when `async void` is used in any method except an event handler. If you want to throttle tasks, use a custom task scheduler or an ActionBlock with a DOP set to the limit you want. To avoid this error ensure all tasks have completed before exiting.

Comment: BTW if you still have the same exception you didn't understand yesterday's answer. The answer is definitely *not* `Task.WaitAll`, in fact that's what *causes* problems in most cases. Tasks should be awaited instead abandoned or blocked. If you want to stop exeuction but don't want an exception, you should cancel waits and awaiting using a CancellationToken

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for your input, you are probably right that I haven't fully understood, which is why I'm still posting! I think I have a solution that is now working based of your comments, so thank you